# Android progress shape loading bar type

Tags: java, android, user-interface, progress-bar, shapes

Not sure how to pin point a definition for what I am looking for. I want a shape, like a circle, diamond, rectangle that has a border with color (lets say black). I then want to press a play button and I want the border of the shape to start being replaced with another color (lets say blue). So it is like a progress bar but that starts from point A, then keeps filling up with a certain color until it reaches point B, or in this case, the same point it started appearing on the shape.

Any implementations, ideas for this type of thing?

Comment: use setProgressDrawable method with a custom Drawable class (a class that extends Drawable)

Comment: @pskink any example implementation?

Comment: only hints if you post what you did so far

Comment: @Not on it yet. Can you point to any examples?

Comment: tried google("android custom drawable class") ?